# Add a unique key to dynamic children without having any unique key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping some arrays in a React project and I return li-tag children, of course React expects a unique key for every dynamic child. However, I don't think I have any unique key... At least, not that I know of. With my data and code (being fetched from https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/instak/chatters), is there any key i can pass?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Overview extends Component{
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      chatters: {
        moderators: [],
        staff: [],
        admins: [],
        global_mods: [],
        viewers: []
      }
   };
}

componentWillMount() {
 fetch('/api/overview') // fetch from Express.js server
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => this.setState({
    chatters: result.chatters
  }));
}

render(){
    let {chatters} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Chatters</h2>
            <div>
                <h3>Moderators</h3>
                <ul>
                {chatters.moderators.map(chatter => {
                    return <li key={chatter.key}>{chatter}</li>;
                })}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Staff</h3>
                <ul>
                {chatters.staff.map(chatter => {
                    return <li key={chatter.key}>{chatter}</li>;
                })}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Admins</h3>
                <ul>
                {chatters.admins.map(chatter => {
                    return <li key={chatter.key}>{chatter}</li>;
                })}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Global Mods</h3>
                <ul>
                {chatters.global_mods.map(chatter => {
                    return <li key={chatter.key}>{chatter}</li>;
                })}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Plebs</h3>
                <ul>
                {chatters.viewers.map(chatter => {
                    return <li key={chatter.key}>{chatter}</li>;
                })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the twitch username. React doesn't need some fancy key, it just needs to be a unique value that stays the same for that individual rendered element.

example:

```
chatters.viewers.map(chatterName => {
  return <li key={chatterName}>{chatterName}</li>;
})
```

Comment: oh wow... I had this vision in my mind of it always being an array of numbers counting up... You're right, every name will suffice as a unique key... Thanks for pointing that out!